# Which toolchain to use for Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, 64-bit, toolchain

I just got my all new Raspberry Pi 3 board. I was wondering which tool-chain to use for my 64-bit pi (BCM2837). In  the official github page I could find tool-chain for previous model only. Please Help

Comment: Cross-toolchain or native? Bare-metal or userspace? Given that by all accounts it's running much the same (32-bit) kernel as the Pi 2, and the exact same userspace image as all the others, in most cases you wouldn't need anything different.

Comment: @Notlikethat I was looking for Cross toolchain. So is you are telling that its not possible to build a 64bit os for Pi3

Comment: Oh, for sure it's _possible_ - I saw people had managed to get a 64-bit kernel and Debian userspace running within days of release - it's just not officially supported, and I have no idea how much hacking is involved in doing so.

Comment: @Notlikethat I was thinking about build a linaro 64bit toolchain to bring up a 64 bit linux version in RPI3. Have you got any idea on the "Architecture level"  and "Emit assembly for CPU" for compiling the tolchain

Comment: Dunno - I've never bothered doing anything more than [grabbing the prebuilt binaries](http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-5.2/).

Comment: @jsaji is your RPi3 already running 64-bit OS e.g. 2021-05-07-raspios-buster-arm64.zip or 2021-05-07-raspios-buster-arm64-lite.zip? Those have 64bit toolchain (gcc etc) already, you don't even need sudo apt-get install gcc

Answer (score 0):

In documentation at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md you can use toolchain from https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools which works with your Raspberry Pi 3 board. You don't need any special toolchains because the kernel is still 32bit and OS (like Raspbian) is at this time only 32 bit. There won't be any other special toolchain for RPi3.

Comment: This toolchain is still using gcc 4.8.3